# Winbind not enumerating users and groups of trusted domain

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, active-directory

I'm using Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu in Ubuntu 14.04, for authenticating users from two domains with a one-way cross-forest trust between them.
Samba machine is joined to DOMAINA, while DOMAINB is the trusted domain.
My aim is to allow users from DOMAINA and DOMAINB to get authenticated in Samba machine.

If I run "wbinfo -u" or "wbinfo -g", only users and groups from DOMAINA get enumerated.

Thus, when I run "getent passwd", only local users and DOMAINA users get listed, and the same with "gentent group".

However, if I run "getent passwd DOMAINB+username", this entry appears:

```
DOMAINB+username:*:51276:50513::/home/username:/bin/bash
```

If I run "getent group DOMAINB+groupname", this entry appears:

```
DOMAINB+groupname:x:60860:
```

As you can see, member of DOMAINB+groupname (DOMAINB+username) doesn't appear.

Additional information, if it helps:

```
wbinfo -m
BUILTIN
COMPUTERNAME
DOMAINA
DOMAINB

wbinfo -i DOMAINB+username
DOMAINB+username:*:51276:50513::/home/username:/bin/bash

wbinfo --group-info=DOMAINB+groupname
DOMAINB+groupname:x:60860:
```

Here's a excerpt of my smb.conf:

```
security = ADS
domain master = no

idmap config * : backend        = tdb
idmap config * : range          = 1000000 - 1999999

idmap config DOMAINA : backend      = rid
idmap config DOMAINA : range        = 10000 - 49999

idmap config DOMAINB : backend      = rid
idmap config DOMAINB : range        = 50000 - 99999

allow trusted domains = yes
winbind trusted domains only = no
winbind use default domain = yes
map untrusted to domain = yes

template shell = /bin/bash
template homedir = /home/%U
winbind enum groups = yes
winbind nested groups = no
winbind expand groups = 2
winbind enum users = yes
winbind refresh tickets = yes
winbind separator = +
client use spnego = yes
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.
Thanks!